# Django, Celery, Redis: AttributeError: module 'imp_expert' has no attribute 'celery'

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, config

Tyring to start `celery -A imp_expert worker -l info` as per the Celery documentation (my project is not named `proj`, it's `imp_expert`)

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/expert/.virtualenvs/semion_expert/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/expert/.virtualenvs/semion_expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "/home/expert/.virtualenvs/semion_expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/expert/.virtualenvs/semion_expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/expert/.virtualenvs/semion_expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 273, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/expert/.virtualenvs/semion_expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 479, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/home/expert/.virtualenvs/semion_expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 501, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/home/expert/.virtualenvs/semion_expert/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 370, in find_app
    found = sym.celery
AttributeError: module 'imp_expert' has no attribute 'celery'
```

I have in `__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

In `celery.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'imp_expert.config.base')

app = Celery('imp_expert')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

In `base.py` (we have `base.py`, `local.py` and `production.py` settings files):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals # At the top

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'pickle']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'

BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'

CELERY_BROKER_URL = env('CELERY_BROKER_URL', default='redis://127.0.0.1:6379')
if CELERY_BROKER_URL == 'django://':
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://'
else:
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = CELERY_BROKER_URL
```

Folder and project structure are:

```
sem_expert
├──config
|  ├──settings
|  |  ├──__init__.py
|  |  ├──base.py
|  |  ├──local.py
|  |  └──production.py
|  ├──__init__.py
|  ├──celery.py
|  ├──urls.py
|  └──wsgi.py
├──imp_expert
|  └──expert
|     └──api
|        └──tasks.py
```

(I'm fully aware it is confusing to have a project named `imp_expert` with an app named `expert` inside of it, but it was done long ago before my time and it'd be more trouble than it's worth to change it right now)

I think I'm not quite clear on how to refer to the config withing `celery.py`, specifically on the line:
`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'imp_expert.config.base')`
Either that or I'm confused as to where I should be pointing `celery` at.

Thanks in advance for help with this matter. I'm still sort of new at this stage of the project.

Django 1.10.8
Celery 4.2.1
Redis 2.10.6

Comment: Have you tried running: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="config.settings" celery -A config worker -l info` -- as it seems that `config` is the package containing both the settings and the `celery` module.

Comment: Not sure what you mean:

Add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="config.settings"` to celery.py?
Or entering all that as a command line?

Comment: Try running the whole thing from the command line. The first part of the line will set the variable and the second part will run Celery with that variable set